# Prove that point $\epsilon$ is inside parallelogram $\iff$ there exists $0<t_1<1,0<t_2<1$ s.t $\epsilon=t_1z_1+(1-t_1-t_2)z_2+t_2z_3$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3$ be three vertices of parallelogram. Prove that point $\epsilon$ is inside parallelogram $\iff$ there exists $0<t_1<1,0<t_2<1$ s.t $\epsilon=t_1z_1+(1-t_1-t_2)z_2+t_2z_3$.And prove that those $t_1,t_2$ are unique.

I wrote $z_i=x_i+y_ii$ for $i=1,2,3$. And got that $\epsilon=t_1(x_1-x_2)+t_2(x_3-x_2)+x_2+t_1y_1i-t_1y_2i+y_2i$ and tried to check if real and imaginary parts satisfied inequality. But I am not sure this is right way to go. Because we also need to prove that those $t_1,t_2$ are unique.

Answer (score 1):

The configurations of three points which don't make a parallelogram are only the collinear and degenerate ones. You should notice that the right hand side is an affine combination that checks exactly for this. Hence, yes, your statement is trivially true.

Anyway, suppose you wrote $\epsilon$ using $t_1 = t_2$ and $z$ is a parallelogram. Since the interior is open, eventually $(t_1 +1/g, t_2-1/g)$ will land us a point $\eta \in \text{int } z$, arbitrarily close to $\epsilon$ for some $g>0$, but with $\eta$ distinct from $\epsilon$, and with $t_1 \neq t_2$. So, you will always be able to guarantee the existence of unique $t_1, t_2 \in (0,1)$ to write a point in the interior of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

A correction to my initial answer:

[image]

Consider first the case where $E$ is in the triangle $DBC$. Then as we see in the picture that $(1),(3)$ imply $(2)$, so we have the three equations that we want and $t_{1}=\lambda$, $t_{2}=(1-\lambda)(1-s)$.

Now consider the case E is in the triangle OBD. We use the fact that $z_{2}=z_{1}+z_{3}$ to rewrite the result as:

$z_{E}=(1-t_{2})z_{1}+(1-t_{1})z_{3}$.

It is clear that $OE=rOC$ where $r<1$. But $OC=\lambda\,z_{1}+(1-\lambda)\,z_{3}$.

So we must have by the linear independence of $z_{1},\,z_{3}$ that $r\lambda=1-t_{2}$ and $r(1-\lambda)=1-t_{1}$.

So, $t_{1}=1-r(1-\lambda)$ and clearly $0<t_{1}<1$

and $t_{2}=1-r\lambda$ and $0<t_{2}<1$. That completes the proof of the statement!

Comment: And if $A$ is on $OB$ then just $t_1+t_2=1$

Comment: Why? If $t_1+t_2=1$ then $OE=\lambda(z_1)+(1-\lambda)z_3$

Comment: I don't understand why you put $r$ where you defined $z_E$

Comment: Then I guess there is a mistake in my book.

Comment: No your book was right! I made a mistake, assuming wrongly that $z_{1},z_{2},z_{3}$ are linearly independent. I have edited a correct proof now!